# Parsing function expressions without variable assignment

Tags: javascript, function

```
var functionExpressionA = function(){
  return x+1;
};

var functionExpressionB = function(){
  return y+1;
};

var y=10;
var x=20;

functionExpressionB(); //returns 11
functionExpressionA(); //returns 21
```

I would like to clarify how hoisting and parsing of this code works in the above example.

My understanding is that the variable names `var y` and `var x` are hoisted. However, **their assignments `10` and `20`** are not hoisted.

If the above is true how is this snippet of Javascript actually parsed by the browser?

With specific interest to the function expressions which contain a variable which at the time of parsing (because of hoisting only the variable name) is `undefined`

Comment: Can you add code too

Comment: A function expression is an anonymous, immediately invoked function. Do you mean function definitions / declarations?

Comment: This is somewhat vague without a code sample. Please share the relevant part of code related the the 4 points, so that the question can be properly analized.

Comment: read about function hoisting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions always get 'dragged to the top'. So your variables will always be loaded later than the func's. Try to load the variables above the functions and it will work. It's called Hoisting.

Comment: @Camille Sébastien Niessen

Functions get hoisted
and
variable names get hoisted.

**But** Does the actual invoking (calling) of the functions have to happen after the variables are assigned their values?

Comment: You can always call the functions `functionExpressionA` and `functionExpressionB`, however if you call them before you have assigned the variables `x` and `y` then your functions will return `NaN` (`undefined + 1 = NaN`) unless you've enabled strict mode in which case it will result in an error.